# how to write a simple .bat code to open command prompt with ping

Tags: windows, command-line, ping

I am working in a HR department and I have to check if  the *biometric machine* is connected to our main server.

Each time I open the run command and type a `ping ip_address -t`.

I just want to automate the process, like some shortcut to the ping command which open cmd screen with pings.

I found this code here, but it's opening a txt file. I want to open a command prompt

here is the code I found.

```
@ECHO OFF

:LOOPSTART

time /T
ping xxx.xx.x.x  -t >> filename.txt
sleep -m 3000

GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Comment: ok, i figured it out, any one can use it, this will open ping command.@ECHO OFF
set IPADDRESS=my ip -t
set INTERVAL=60
:PINGINTERVAL
ping %IPADDRESS% 
timeout %INTERVAL%
GOTO PINGINTERVAL

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). Please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `>>` and everything after on that line.

Removing the redirection `>` or `>>` changes the output of the command so that it writes to the terminal instead of to the file `filename.txt`